# Storing a range in a variable

Tags: vba, excel

i need to put in a variable a range of values, i.e. the variable

```
tsPeriod(1) = (3, 4, 5)
tsPeriod(3) = (1, 2, 3).
```

I don't know what kind of variable to declare and how to do it. I've tried to do something like this:

```
Dim tsPeriod() as long
ReDim tsPeriod(nSub) as long
for i = 1 to nSub
   tsPeriod(i) = (tsStart(i), tsEnd(i))
next
```

But it doesnt work that way and im kinda lost how to put that "range" into that variable. (if the first value is 3 and the second is 6 i want the variable to retrieve (3, 4, 5, 6))

Below is part of the code:

```
Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = ThisWorkbook

Dim subjects As Worksheet
Set subjects = wb.Sheets("Subject")

Dim nSub As Integer, nRooms As Integer

nSub= subjects.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).value

Dim tsStart() As Long
ReDim tsStart(nSub) As Long

For i = 1 To nSub
    tsStart(i) = subjects.Cells(i + 1, 3).value
Next

Dim tsBusy() As Long
ReDim tsBusy(numDis) As Long

For i = 1 To nSub
    tsBusy(i) = subjects.Cells(i + 1, 4).value
Next

Dim tsEnd() As Long
ReDim tsEnd(nSub) As Long

For i = 1 To nSub
    tsEnd(i) = tsStart(i) + tsBusy(i) - 1
Next

'Here's where im having trouble
Dim tsPeriod() As Long
ReDim tsPeriod(nSub) As Long

For i = 1 To nSub
    tsPeriod(i) = (tsStart(i), TsEnd(i))
Next
```

Comment: There is no built-in "range" method in VBA: you need to dimension an array of the required size and fill it using a loop.

Comment: `numDis` is never initialized. Is it to be always intended as `numSub`?

Comment: @user3598756 yes, it is nSub. I've translated the code to english and forgot to change it haha. thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built-in "range" method in VBA: you need to dimension an array of the required size and fill it using a loop.  You can create a function to do this:

```
Function RRange(startNum, endNum)
   Dim rv() as long, i
   Redim rv(1 to (endnum-startnum)+1)
   for i = startNum to endNum
       rv((i-startNum)+1) = i
   next i
   RRange = rv
End Function
```

Then:

```
For i = 1 To numDis
    tsPeriod(i) = RRange(tsStart(i), TsEnd(i))
Next
```

Comment: Some comments: 1) `rv((startNum-i)+1) = i`i should be `rv((i - startNum) + 1) = i` 2) `tsPeriod` must be declared as an array of `Variant` type: `ReDim tsPeriod() As Variant` 3) OP can get rid of all arrays `Dim` statements and leave only their `ReDim` ones

Comment: Ok, i've tried it, but i have one more doubt: why cant i debug.print it?

Comment: You can't print an array like that... use the "add watch" the see all values

Comment: It worked like a charm, thank you! Also, i've declared it as `ReDim tsPeriod(1 to nSub) as Variant`, because declaring it as `ReDim tsPeriod() As Variant` would return error 9. (thanks for the redim tip either, it will made the code much clearer!)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the combination of `Application.Transpose`, `Evaluate` and the worksheets-`ROW` function to get there.

For the

```
tsPeriod(i) = (tsStart(i), TsEnd(i))
```

simply use

```
tsPeriod(i) = Application.Transpose(Evaluate("=ROW(" & tsStart(i) & ":" & tsEnd(i) & ")"))
```

To get an array from the first to the last value.
To just get a comma-separated string, put this in a `Join` like this

```
tsPeriod(i) = Join(Application.Transpose(Evaluate("=ROW(" & tsStart(i) & ":" & tsEnd(i) & ")")), ",")
```

`Join` also is good for testing if everything is fine, because you can use `Debug.Print`.